# Python - Using ifs, elifs and else in list comprehensions with their respective results

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I was thinking if it was possible to write ifs and elifs and elses in a list comprehension with specifying what thing we need to do if that expression becomes true. I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
print(list(x for x in range(1,101) if x%3 == 0 print("Fizz")))
```

I am using Python 3.3.4.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're expecting this code to do.

Comment: I am expecting what @thefourtheye told. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write another `if` condition in the `if`'s Truthy part or the `else`'s Truthy part, like this

```
print(["FizzBuzz" if x%15 == 0 else "Fizz" if x%3 == 0 else "Buzz" if x % 5 == 0 else x for x in range(1,101)])
```

Readable version:

```
print(["FizzBuzz"
          if x%15 == 0
          else
             "Fizz"
                 if x%3 == 0
                 else
                   "Buzz"
                      if x % 5 == 0
                      else
                         x
       for x in range(1,101)])
```

Comment: :P You got what my program was about :P